# "limit" vs. "limit point" of a sequence in a topological space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence, nets

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$.

> I'm highly confused by the notion of a *limit point* $x\in E$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

If $\tau$ is induced by a metric $d$, then I usually mean that $d(x_n,x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, when I say that $x$ is a "limit point" of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. It's actually *the* limit point, since $x$ must be unique. This terminology differs from $x$ being an "accumulation point", which usually means that there is an increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$ with $d(x_{n_k},x)\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$.

Now, in the context of general topology, I've seen statements like "$x$ is a limit point of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ if and only if there is a subnet $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which converges to $x$". But this sounds more like a generalization of the characterization of an accumulation point.

Moreover, it seems like one distinguishes between "limit points" and "limits" of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. If I'm not missing something, the "limit" of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is unique in Hausdorff spaces. So, at least in the Hausdorff case, it wouldn't make much sense to talk about "a" limit point, since it must be unique.

> So, how are these terms precisely defined and related?

If it matters, I'm mostly interested in the case where $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $\tau$ is the weak topology on $E$.

Comment: It depends on the author. Typically "limit point" = "accumulation point". While "limit" of a net $\alpha$ is "a point $x\in X$ such that for any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, our $\alpha$ is eventually in $U$". Which for metric case translates to $d(\alpha_n, x)\to 0$.

Comment: @freakish So, if it is an accumulation point, it means that there is a subnet which converges to $x$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#For_sequences_and_nets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limit point (or accumulation point) $p$ for a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in a space $X$, is a point that the sequence gets close to infinitely often:

> For all open sets $O_p$ containing $x$ (or epsilon ball around $p$ if you prefer in  a metric space) and every index $n$ there is an index $m > n$ such that $x_m \in U$.

This notion can be defined for any net defined on some directed index set $I$, of course. If $X$ is first countable (as in a metric space) this means that we can define a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $p$: just take the countable local nested base $U_n(p)$ around $p$ and recursively choose increasing $n_k$ so that $x_{n_k} \in U_k(p)$ for $k \in \Bbb N$. 
More generally, in any space and a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ we can choose a subnet of the net that converges to $p$ when $p$ is a limit point of the net. This sort of explains the name: it's a limit of a subnet (or subsequence in metric context).

A limit of the sequence is much stronger: there *all* points of the tail of a sequence have to lie in any neighbourhood of the limit, not just infinitely many. Limits in Hausdorff spaces are unique, while a sequence can have more limit points. A trivial example of this is an alternating sequence like $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$, e.g.: no limit but two limit points.

There are also notions of limit point of a set, and accumulation point of a set, which do not need to have a link with sequences. So mind the context in the terminology..

Comment: Weak topologies on Banach spaces are Hausdorff so limits are unique. They are but rarely first countable.